# Touchpad not recognized on Lenovo ThinkBook 14-IML

Tags: touchpad, lenovo

I purchased a Lenovo ThinkBook 14-IML and obviously have Ubuntu installed on it. It's a great machine and runs Ubuntu well, but I just can't use the trackpad. Below are the outputs from various commands I've seen on other posts...

`xinput`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech M510                             id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

`cat /proc/bus/input/devices`:

```
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="Lid Switch"
P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0C/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=LNXPWRBN/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab83
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event3 leds 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=402000000 3803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Ideapad extra buttons"
P: Phys=ideapad/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/PNP0C09:00/VPC2004:00/input/input14
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=rfkill kbd event5 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=81000800100c03 4400000000300000 0 2
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=04f2 Product=b6d9 Version=2699
N: Name="Integrated Camera: Integrated C"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-6/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/input/input15
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event6 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input16
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event7 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Mic"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input17
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event8 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=10

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Headphone"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input18
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event9 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=4

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input19
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event10 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input20
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event11 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input21
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event12 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input22
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event13 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input23
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event14 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=046d Product=4051 Version=0111
N: Name="Logitech M510"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input2:1
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0007/0003:046D:4051.0008/input/input24
U: Uniq=4051-a2-0a-45-28
H: Handlers=mouse0 event4 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=ffff0000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=1943
B: MSC=10
```

If you need outputs from anything else, let me know and I will get them posted.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In the [lenovo forums](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Ubuntu/ThinkBook-14-IML-ELAN-TouchPad-Not-Recognized-Ubuntu/m-p/4622518?page=1), people reported that updating the BIOS to CJCN2508 and building the linux kernel with a patch (which looked like it was going upstream) enabled trackpad on this platform.

Comment: perhaps you like to get the points as i found it through your link https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Ubuntu/ThinkBook-14-IML-ELAN-TouchPad-Not-Recognized-Ubuntu/m-p/4622518?page=2#5072125 -- make it a proper and nice answer and it will be all yours ;)

Comment: I'm currently running CJCN27WW, which was released on March 31, 2020. Still no luck, even after applying that Grub text.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201910-27453) your laptop was certified for 18.04, so this seems odd.

First of all you have to make sure your bios-version is (atleast): CJCN2508.

Then there might be a possible solutions:

- try the oem-kernel; run `sudo apt install linux-oem-20.04` in a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>)

If this does not work:

- install 18.04.4 and then install the oem-kernel: `sudo apt install linux-oem`
- i also found something promising: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Ubuntu/ThinkBook-14-IML-ELAN-TouchPad-Not-Recognized-Ubuntu/m-p/4622518?page=2#5072125

Comment: Do you think it's worth posting my dmesg results?

Comment: @user2321023 try to upgrade the bios/uefi to the latest - dkcn29ww released this month and then add the grub option according to the lenovo-forums post linked in my answer

Comment: according to the Lenovo site, I am up to date on BIOS/UEFI. Where are you seeing that one at?

https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkbook-series/thinkbook-14-iml/downloads/driver-list/component?name=BIOS%2FUEFI